# Unable to update table joined with itself

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to update the table but it gives me the following error:

UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row.

I am supposed to update housing_1 with this query but the update function has to be linked to an dataset.

```
UPDATE
  my-project-19297-401423.housing_analysis.housing_data
SET
  PropertyAddress = ifnull(housing_1.PropertyAddress,housing_2.PropertyAddress)
FROM
  my-project-19297-401423.housing_analysis.housing_data AS housing_1
JOIN
  my-project-19297-401423.housing_analysis.housing_data AS housing_2
ON
  housing_1.ParcelID = housing_2.ParcelID
AND
  housing_1.UniqueID_ <> housing_2.UniqueID_
WHERE
  housing_1.PropertyAddress is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the join, but that the query returns more than one result per updated dataset. Please give the original table, which shall be update, a name.

First, generate a dummy table as a minmal working example. `Test` is a dataset.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Test.housing AS
SELECT
  addr||tmp AS PropertyAddress,
  ParcelID,
  rand() UniqueID_
FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("A B C D E F G H"," ")) AS addr WITH OFFSET ParcelID,
  UNNEST(["",NULL]) AS tmp
```

Then we obtain the best address from any ParcelID using the `group by` and have only one row for each entry. In the `WHERE` clause the `ParcelID` of both tables have to match. Of course only missing entries shall be updated:

```
org_table.PropertyAddress IS NULL
```

```sql
UPDATE
  Test.housing AS org_table
SET
  PropertyAddress = IFNULL(org_table.PropertyAddress,PropertyAddress_best_guess)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ParcelID,
    ANY_VALUE(PropertyAddress) AS PropertyAddress_best_guess
  FROM
    Test.housing
  GROUP BY
    ParcelID ) AS ref_tbl
WHERE
  org_table.PropertyAddress IS NULL
  AND org_table.ParcelID = ref_tbl.ParcelID
```